Flattening a likelihood
Background
Let $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_K$ be a sequence of measurements.
I've derived a likelihood $\mathcal{L}(y|i)$ to solve a classification problem via the Bayesian classifier
\begin{equation}
p_k(i)=\frac{\mathcal{L}(y_k|i)\,p_{k-1}(i)}{\sum_{\nu=1}^n \mathcal{L}(y_k|\nu)\,p_{k-1}(\nu)} \qquad i=1,\dots,n
\end{equation}
starting from the uniform prior $p_0(i)\triangleq1/n$. The main issue of $\mathcal{L}(y_k|i)$ is that it tends to be "overconfident", in the sense that for almost all class gets negligible values except, say, for one or two classes. As a consequence of this fact, $p_k(i)$ converges to a Dirac distribution using few measurements, say two, with no guarantees that the asymptotic distribution is centered on the correct class.
In simple words, my classifier is "hasty" and often its final answer is wrong.
Solution
To solve this problem, I perform a "flattening" transformation of the likelihood which tends to equalize the class values of $\mathcal{L}(y|i)$. Inspired by the softmax classifier, the transformation that I consider is
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\mathcal{L}}(y|i)\triangleq \exp\left(\frac{\mathcal{L}(y|i)}{\tau}\right)
\qquad i=1,\dots,n
\end{equation}
where $\tau>0$ is a parameter that controls the aggressivity of the flattening action. The resulting classifier
\begin{equation}
p_k(i)=\frac{\tilde{\mathcal{L}}(y_k|i)\,p_{k-1}(i)}{\sum_{\nu=1}^n \tilde{\mathcal{L}}(y_k|\nu)\,p_{k-1}(\nu)} \qquad i=1,\dots,n
\end{equation}
allows to arbitrarily slow down (via $\tau$) the convergence rate of the posterior, so that
it is possible to enforce the visualization of all measurements before reaching the ending Dirac distribution. By doing this, the chances that the ending answer of the classifier is correct increase and by slowing down enough the convergence the classifier often guess the correct class.
Questions
The likelihood model $\mathcal{L}(y|i)$ is derived with no approximations from a measurement model that is used to generate the sequence of measurements. From this fact I would say that the best thing to do (from a mathematical and a practical point of view) is to just consider the "raw" likelihood $\mathcal{L}(y|i)$.
However the "flattened" likelihood $\tilde{\mathcal{L}}(y|i)$, which does not follow the true measurement model behind the measurements, leads to better performances.
My questions are the following.

Is it possible to "retro-engineering" the measurement model behind the heuristic likelihood $\tilde{\mathcal{L}}(y|i)$?
Is there a rigorous way to solve the issue of my "hasty" classifier?
What is in general the meaning of the exponential of a likelihood?

If necessary, I can provide more detail about my classification problem.

Could you please add an explanation for how you derived the expression for $p_k(i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$? I am curious to know where it came from.

Its just the Bayes theorem: $\text{posterior}\propto \text{likelihood} \cdot \text{prior}$

Could you explain in what sense $p_k(i)$ is a posterior? As in, in simple words, what is $p_k(i)$ and how does it relate to the sequence of measurements $y_1,\dots,y_K$? For example, one usually reads posterior probabilities in the form $\Pr(X = x \mid Y = y)$. How would you express $p_k(i)$ in this form? I think answering these two questions could shed some more light here.
